# jQuery SlideIn Animation to CSS Animation in Angular

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

Yesterday I tried to create a slidein effect of three overlapping divs in CSS Animation but failed. Even though angular provides the extra classes I was not able to accomplish a smooth transition.

What I would like to achieve can be seen here (solved with jQuery): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVpyvB

[image: Animation I try to create in CSS]

My problem with the css animation was, that either the underlaying div would be removed to soon (transition from div1 to div2) or there was a small flicker effect when finally the underlaying div should be hidden.

So what's the correct way to move from these jQuery statements to CSS Animation?

```
$('#show2').click(function(){
  $('.second').animate({
    'margin-left': '0px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.first').removeClass('visible');
    $('.second').addClass('visible');
  });
});

$('#hide2').click(function(){
  $('.first').addClass('visible');
  $('.second').removeClass('visible');
  $('.second').animate({'margin-left': '350px'}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't included your CSS, I have made a guess and built my own version of it, have a look if the below helps you in any way. The JS is simply there to add and remove classes and could be replaced by jQuery if you want, but it's fairly simply.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('container');
var cd = Array.prototype.slice.call(c.querySelectorAll('div'));

// Make each #d activate the next one (where available)
cd.forEach(function(e, i){
    // Check each for a close anchor
    var a = e.querySelector('a');
    if(a) a.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        cd[i].className = '';
    })
    // Check if there is a next element to activate
    if(cd[i + 1]) e.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        cd[i + 1].className = 'active';
    })
});

// Make Container Click active #d1
c.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    cd[0].className = 'active';
})
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container > div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  /* This would be all you need */
  -webkit-transition: left 400ms;
  transition: left 400ms;
}
/* And this, of course. */
#container > div.active {
  left: 20%;
}
#d1 { background: yellow; }
#d2 { background: red; }
#d3 { background: green; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id='d1'>First <a href="#">Close</a></div>
  <div id='d2'>Second <a href="#">Close</a></div>
  <div id='d3'>Third <a href="#">Close</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your solution the child divs always position absolute. In my case I need them to be positioned relative when the animation ends. Please take a look at the source provided in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVpyvB

Comment: @Steve But _why_? You are only making it hard on yourself here.

Comment: @somthinghere because the whole design needs it to fit for all screentypes.  (The code at codepen is just a snippet) So is there a way to accomplish this with the css I put into codepen?

Comment: No, not really. You could by adding more classes (one which says 'this is active but not the current one'), but it increases complexity a lot. I don't see why this would not work since all your divs, including the inactive ones, are originally `absolute` anyhow. What difference does `absolute` make here? As in, there is no direct difference between what happens on small nor large screen sizes. Also, since there is only one class being added, you could easily use media queries to make a different animation for different screen sizes...